# How to get value in LinkedList which have two values

Tags: java, linked-list

I have three variables in the linked list (take an example, StudentID, Group, Priority)

I have used the following codes for the program:

```
public String toString() {
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
    String str = " ";

    ListNode current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        str += "StudentID: " + StudentAdd.getStudentID() + " is in Group " +
            StudentAdd.getGroup().toUpperCase() + " with priority " + 
            StudentAdd.getPriority();
            str += "]\n";
            current = current.getNext();

        }
        
        return str;
    }
```

I would like to get the following outputs

```
[StudentID:0001 is in Group A with Priority 1]
[StudentID:0005 is in Group C with Priority 1]
[StudentID:0220 is in Group B with Priority 2]
[StudentID:0200 is in Group B with Priority 2]
[StudentID:0215 is in Group B with Priority 2]
[StudentID:0315 is in Group B with Priority 3]
[StudentID:0301 is in Group B with Priority 3]
[StudentID:0350 is in Group B with Priority 3]
```

However, the I only got the following output

```
[StudentID:0350 is in Group B with Priority 3]
[StudentID:0350 is in Group B with Priority 3]
[StudentID:0350 is in Group B with Priority 3]
[StudentID:0350 is in Group B with Priority 3]
[StudentID:0350 is in Group B with Priority 3]
[StudentID:0350 is in Group B with Priority 3]
[StudentID:0350 is in Group B with Priority 3]
[StudentID:0350 is in Group B with Priority 3]
```

It just displayed the last input of the student.

So how could I update it?

Comment: Well, you're using `StudentAdd` for all the printing, which I guess is the last student you added. `current` is not used for anything else than just going through the list.

Comment: @JamesZ, in `StudentAdd.java` will be the getter and setter for storing and getting the StudentID, groups, and Priority. 
In `LinkedList.java` will be `add` for being `AddToHead` or `AddToTail`. 

Also a `toString()` program will be stored in `LinkedList.java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer "current" node in the while loop instead of "StudentAdd", something like below

```
while (current != null) {
    str += "StudentID: " + current.getStudentID() + " is in Group " +
        current.getGroup().toUpperCase() + " with priority " + 
        current.getPriority();
        str += "]\n";
        current = current.getNext();

    }
```

Comment: Well, I had tried to get the data, while it displayed as `StudentAdd@5fd0d5ae` , which can't displays the value which I would like to get. How could I get the value in the class?